# Sine wave signal at resonant frequency gets distorted

Tags: frequency, sine, single-supply-op-amp

I am currently at lost on what I need to do to solve my problem.
I have a sine wave signal as my input, and the output is sine wave as well. At resonant frequency, the output of the signal gets high.  I was able to get good signal output using function generator, but I am not getting a similar result using a circuitry. The input signal gets distorted when it is in resonant frequency. From the image below, purple is the output and the yellow is the input. I am currently using an inverting amplifier to output a gain of 10. [DDS module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0085N592S) outputs a positive sine wave with 1Vpk-pk. With the inverting gain of 10, it outputs 10Vpk-pk. After using AC coupling in oscilloscope, it goes -5V to +5V (yellow) as shown in the image below. At resonant, the yellow signal gets distorted.
What can I do to not have distortion when it is in resonant frequency. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
Distorted signal when in-phase

[image]

No distortion when out of phase
[image]

Comment: Please label the output on the schematic.

Comment: @Mattman944, added output label. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: You are probably exceeding the capability of the second opamp. Reduce your input amplitude. Probe the top of the inductor to learn more.

Comment: @Mattman944, you are spot on with the fact that if I do reduce the amplitude down to 3V, I see a little distortion. The opamp I am using is TSH82 from sparkfun. I measured the voltage after the inductor, and it does go up to 53V; I believe this an inductive kick. What opamp should I look for to deal with this issue?

Comment: Put values on your components and explain what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Increase the supply voltage or reduce the amplitude.

Comment: @Mattman944, testing out circuitry to learn. That's all.

Comment: Purple doesn't look distorted. Yellow looks distorted.

Comment: @Andyaka Purple is the output, and yellow is the input. The distortion is in the yellow signal when it is at resonant frequency. I am changed my explanation. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @user_1818839 is there a possibility of changing the opamp and getting no distortion instead of increasing supply voltage or reducing the amplitude?

Comment: What value is the resistor at the output?

Comment: @Sam - you still haven't put values on the L, C, R. If you do, we can simulate the circuit. At resonance, the current output demands on the opamp may be beyond the capability of the opamp.

Comment: @Mattman944, I have added everything now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that R =20 ohms, at resonance, the peak value of Vout is more than 4 volts.

I(R1) = V/R = 4/20 = 200 mA!

This is a series circuit, so the opamp output current is the same. This is way beyond the capability of this opamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSLb3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Or, by analysis ...

At resonance, the LC impedance is zero, so the opamp must be able to drive the resistor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#Series_circuit

Comment: So the distortion is not related to the Gain Bandwidth product but due to the lack of power that causes distortion.Hmm

Comment: If you are just experimenting, change the resistor to 1k. If you need this to work at low resistances, there are high-power opamps (expensive).

Comment: I increased the resistor value to 200ohm and I didn't see distortion anymore. What's interesting is when I put in 5K ohms, the output is always in phase with the input. Do you by any chance know why the input and the output are always in phase when the resistance is high?

Comment: With a larger value resistor the resonant peak will be less sharp. There will still be phase shift if you go far enough from the center frequency.

Answer (score 0):

LM358 has unity gain at 1.1MHz. Lets look at LM358 datasheet. [image: Open Loop Frequency Response]

At 200kHz voltage gain is between 6 and 15 and has quite big hysteresis (thats why you have more disortion on negative half). You are just limited by bandwith of opamp. At 161kHz max gain is better and you see no disiortion.

Comment: I am currently using TSH82, and it has a Gain bandwidth product of 10Mhz, and -3dB at 100MHz per datasheet. Isn't that more than sufficient?